# Error JSS Editing Secret

Tags: jss, xm-cloud, rendering-host

Finally, I configured a headless project on my `xmcloud.localhost`. An error exists when I try to access a page from my Headless local with `Experience Manager`.

> Error: "Connection to your rendering host failed with an Unauthorized
> error.Ensure the JSS Editing Secret is configured.".

My localhost:3000 works fine, but when I try to open it in Experience Manager, it fails.

I configured in `.env` (from .env generated when I ran ./up.ps1) - `JSS_EDITING_SECRET`, it appears in config files xml page.

Also, I added
Server side rendering engine endpoint URL [shared]:
`http://localhost:3000/api/editing/render`

ServerSideRenderingEngineApplicationUrl [shared]:
`http://localhost:3000`
Also, if I try to open `sitecore/content/Home`, it works on Default Sitecore Website, but on my headless local experience editor does not work.

Do you have any idea how to solve this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have checked everything is OK with the `JSS_EDITING_SECRET` configuration, please follow these steps to solve your issue:

1. Leave blank these fields on the Settings item:

[image]

2. Create a local rendering host item on `/sitecore/system/Settings/Services/Rendering Hosts` with the following values:

Server Side Rendering Engine Endpoint Url: http://rendering:3000/api/editing/render

Server side rendering engine application URL: http://rendering:3000

Application Name : `your app name`

[image]

3. In `/sitecore/content/yourApp/yourApp/Settings/Site Grouping/yourApp` item, change the Default rendering host for the Local item created before.

[image]

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error, run your `/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx` and ensure that the `JssEditingSecret` property exists with a properly formatted value.

```
<setting
  name="JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.JssEditingSecret"
  value="00DC00FC0E000000BA0E000000DC0000"
/>
```

It should be in `/App_Config/Include/zzz/(your-app-name).config`. If you see the file but it's not in your config do an IIS reset.

Also please make sure this section has been uncommented in your config file because when did this (late 2022) it was commented out by default.

[image]

Reference: https://www.getfishtank.com/blog/troubleshooting-errors-for-sitecore-headless-sxa-next-js-xm-cloud-setup

**Update:**

Ensure the value of `JSS_EDITING_SECRET=` in your `.env` file matches the value in your `JssEditingSecret` property in your `/App_Config/Include/zzz/(your-app-name).config`.

Read more details [here](https://rockpapersitecore.com/2023/06/connection-to-your-rendering-host-failed-with-an-unauthorized-error-ensure-the-jss-editing-secret-is-configured/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Sumit, i run my showconfig.aspx and JssEditingSecret exists. On sitecore/content/home, it works fine, but when i enter to my headless project, it doesnt work and have same error.

Comment: Check the log of rendering host to see if any other potential error logged.

Comment: Sorry, but where can i see the log of rendering Host? Thanks

Comment: You can see the logs either using docker desktop, or by running `docker logs your-redering-name`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are using an `XM Cloud starter kit`, XM Cloud uses container and containers have specific URLs for the sites for internal communication

Your CM URL is `https://CM` likewise, your rendering host runs on `http://rendering`  URL

So try using `http://rendering:3000` instead of `http://localhost:3000` and keep the remaining part the same

If you want to use `http://localhost:3000` then you can stop your rendering container first and then you will have to start an app using
`jss start:connected` or `npm run start:connected` depending on the package.json, one app runs on that port then you will be able to use `http://localhost:3000` as rendering host urls

But generally, frontend developers who do not have docker and connecting to a remote host generally use the latter approach

With the docker container, you should only use `http://rendering:3000`

Let me know if you want to connect or know more to troubleshoot this

Answer (score 0):

Check `env` file of your rendering host. Make sure `JSS_EDITING_SECRET` is filled there and matches with secret in Sitecore. Restart the rendering host and it should work.